# Echarts: How can I show the line curvy instead of straight

Tags: javascript, charts, dashboard, echarts

I'm trying to achieve show long curves/lines on the line chart between small numbers.

Here is an example of this: [echarts example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8BvAULWAiA5gJwgE3QC5YU010BPI2AZgFYAaVMygJmtdabIwA9qALAIB0jZuV7tiARjrMAvtz4BBXhADO1UizAUQAU2roAxgEMw-zMGxUl5POdPUA2uJasADJwC0HgGy-rAAqHgCchB4eER7CkR4AWuh27l6svgFeQdJRkdGxkYnJ5J4-_oFZ0tF5cYVuxanp5dKsVZH5CUl1GCVpZZnSNK0xNZ089aUZwdICQ-21Y90NfVN0syNFixNNfmsFo2PoPY39AOy7HRuHS5NZABzn8wdHy1nhuW3rXVdbmZ4P-zxvr0bqxKu9hntLs8QS1wXMASkfsFWIM4Z8FkDjjQQjlcfCoddfNiPGC8einoSPMTYWTIV9oUSQqjaRd6ZTiTM0XSMQyqSFVlzWTz2SEdoLHoDecSzuKEeNgYyPPdZQSfsS3iyJYiFXzsv9VTrsdJSdVuRS1VkaaahebDVlmdatfKsVlOZq5Zs7bJ9WyLdIxe6DS7pDLA76vcqw8K_RrHR7MX1sX8VeGXaCfdG7ZwM7a0w6PmbJZSBDic0WfiWSWXtcdK1aCzbyzrK_mIY2a31K2640HO_zq86-_4B57ayFQz3U0PI5PM2OwiOExkS3qU3O-8bF7yV_W207RxvW_ip8vXVvi1kBVHcxuA7Ob6eQ-eK3dn83Xm-x8nr02vyaG_uS6-CW2Zrg-wFBCin59HQpZgb-MEhP-e7xrysFeNBGToUe5IIVhITdgBqGUuhV73nhvjoXeRG9vhHgTjRJ6USEM6MeudGxmx4EeLBq4_h2-GbvBAnMc0mGiThhYiTxZ7CYOglkVxFEyf64kqQxKG0aJrGaUxKmcbp7HMd-5HSbB6ZyQe-Ggfx8nGZJ7Z2f4cG2VZ6RIWpfghLux5Gc5VKeQRgU8cF1GGdxXn0cFOm-RFIQGbFyleXxplOclyGJdJyU-bhWX2oF0wFYp4VJVkYWZWlWQaRVbnOdIMW5ZV0gJY1tVeSZSl5RZrlAc5NmpW1kEOYBvInC5A29WNVaWZN3lqVNw3ET8U2ESV0lTcVNWzcOM2jeO80sQdC67ZSY0pZ1TlnRlrWzWJJ3Lfl906mdq1bXt3pPccZ3lTd73Vb9p2vp9fRnS1UmXZBuITXt3XQ4D_UXbVY1QcDGS3ONiO9ej009by2M5eDtXY4tWlKkFqO-Njm0Az82M_YTWP7RTZNKmp2Ng45RNZFDmN4xUbOWgLAxC69NM6ujH245SEv05zjNPszEsNQzfPNQLHVrU56Ow7z0uQQTct8yjUs_KEGOa7VZs43DptzczVsk3pVuiyrlJW9Tru2ztJs6lb_2e77h32_F_xuAAusk6CmGo6gADIQNAhjENogIADYJ_oADKuip0nJBdOQxjAKn1hGAAxAAYtIFd0BXoToF08huIobhRzHsemAARvoqdaF8Rcl9g5ehAIyg0AAQrcDc8C3gLRxoQQQMYADWfcYqY6eYNAADqEBgAAFh33e98QYDYAArvolzp4n2cULna8LBgA-l8Q6BlyPY-T9PYxNzPChKHQGAYAxdIAgEfuQM-EBMCYH0EPN-89NCR30LwM-pgADC6h1BBBQWAIwndrB4Dgd4bApg8AQHPuoQgsgQC8AANywBAGQ8h0BMAyFYLQ2AND6GwAIbwbw6h95kOAAAd2IB4ThEjeCwE8Jw7AmBO6mAABTTD8AwLhAg1EaK0TEaQABKBhiiV44GAOfaAeBvAv2wMQER-8976EMYQuBMhOHqGLvgWAldq611CHQn-s8MAUFUBoCBGBdAGCMAANw3pfBE6B1BmAfqfC-V9W7qBAOnMA8dE6hPIDfLOOc84pwOFY8uVca51x_v_GekdEFHx7rk5-xdX4YA_qPCeU9m61JjovFejT4n71EdQAAZhvdQ-gumtzqRnfp-S75JPzk_Jpg8yneMqY3S4gihnJMvs3ABzB0C51geYvurdgHgPEZHJheAWGYBcF0MQCxsjh0jgnUwxhICRP0Og5p8DWmfw6XEpeMAjDGAgNgYwD9I4WFQfMop_dfnl2NPVVgJwqmwD_hiwB4zcD6E0MQVwPBinkGgKYAAtnnQ5G9DCXAcGAJwBKC5cNiKwW4NBWV-BoCcAQJx2W3C4Ey6QLK2WsBHnQUItwSQnF5WowVwqThUmaPRAQ9AaACA2GgIVXhbi3GmKCUINAvChD8CajVzLtWhFYAITwxpbgnAlTQM1WrWWWroNag1HLQQCqWc624lqTVcrtcqvw3qn6-stScW4fg3V0DZbq24TrhWWtCF4Q1_LuX-ETRaw1qi6B5t5XQE4WaXU0GaDq9lCrbgCEeWGpN7LNGaPFdMY0xa_U0HoCcTgnKDWWtbQaugrA6BKkHQIKkNanl1r8CcAdqLRWOrldm-1qKVXGslaGid2aU2sqjeyq186fVJtHc1E4fhZCyF5X2gQAxbiFt5aCAQCaF0uutQIf1mi_XSEvTQPwOrZC6unfu2tFqhB-s4KOmgUbx1jHDZoni4qb1XoNZek4shPBXvZaES9_LjUkjoBB_ll6e30VCCm6drbOV-C8LIFNUrMNPpvSPLw1brXfovfRn9EqZVsoGEW9joRshDtYD-hVdGD3ar8JagY7L21csHeRj1eHZCUfVXxlV4qFV4a8PJmN9EvDRv9K2hVQgx3GZU2J1lCrOUztCHh9tUGeC-oVdO6YJ6QMScM0qE1JqR7-sfeZoNoQUOaMjQOwDG6LPZCrX4a1qQ8OGeNBGzt_KlTxcNZwOgU6P32bII55tdr7UQbvfFgdJ7T3tulbK_zKGKM6pTTZjwZmgMRe5da5qnBp2Vaa3a-qGWVWvrZZ18L3XjWNoo_WwznhJVhBTQJ3jVX9XTBs0JkMomuvRtfVSKN6W5tranQMEep6R70EM5Kg1D7o0SYyydzw9BmgGqYyd0t0no2FuaCd61vX_B-oHSdvDTbIOvvXdB-VUbrV2rdSiE9J2OuBbZaqnbQ3I1Rslc1EN6WTuw8NZRk1V36P2rCLyyNKqQ2NcR5aniQmH02eNYZg1zQ3WlqtZy2nH3qdquaqtsnf283NDC8D7V9rougmlRDsjePAuFqo1eodfOHPyolRJzz4qLu04lV9kbDHW1TYO52uDNBOf8-3V4BrfrdUmoM_RyVab1shgfbLnLwrJUvqVPRVl9vNUspTdGwdpbEM_r801_j4qJecAY9W4tEbC38uPbqoHcujWosV9xybzUI-oqt_4EXEO0_2tt-K1ldALfmctWu-rxrWU8rT7q0dVbp02dJ4bkvg7edJc4HHh3Ce2Wvdu9W_XVeeXHuN1ywbjeC8DaEFuqHT6S8SZ4ym_lbKq_2ola66drKq-Wp5SR_l0W08pq5fQAdYQf179kKW-qu67V76ExlybTb3fmtFXO6VZuA1Tr33bzlTuwjZY9wntn2-0wjOe-CqSozQqKYQD-zqya_6Jur6L2e-ya_o_G6G7ef-oq9UVaJGPK6mJ-0-zUOq_gbqAw0wEepa_G0WMmP6PEZBJQbWU6Vqma0-7K0wkQ8-Qm0atBPulOQgd2tB36HakQd6v-j-HqOBuqXuOqtBsa8BGmD2zBQmxqp6QgSOn6Ch8aqGp69EIh0BGGKIYqNm7mzBhq9AkQf67-xhsgveQ6Q64exhQm9EEm5usaZB5W4qjar6IYrhA6puFW0WDe8ec636_hxqkWXhxh0qJGSqlmARHeQRoGmi_o9UI-gRZ2JIVI-Obqdhxe7OF-_gJIV6ZBrWgWaq5avazBKqXK_oKIVIcm0-EWeaPKJIdqaBohaaqKOaoqPaEeo60akq-eLRUBnuo63KQ6IaPE2OPRYQAwhaGW9A1qPR2QpaN6nAVIEGixqigWI6IaKRcRI89OnKr6-uVqix36A61OxBOhwxLmsxWRheCOje0uN6teJucW0-V6CqrKKIIYJx7x9UKGZx_GyOixDq9UEqt-QxRqMW4J_W3KQmPRqxbK9qTaNO7x3xUaGmbWrR0BL6HR2qp2DxqRH2IxXuCq36CJ0WOqkqVabqux6BI8qKyu7aHBCJUanGkQEGAwCJEqPGoOhaPRhq_GuGKIkJoq3a3unKHale0-3KEmxmkaAhVxRqLxNmea9EEG2JnuVaEhWOoqVaahxeWBaaheUaRegeN6DW7KlpL-mpypheea4qFOCpEeKxU6XKheSoN6LpeGp2zQzU9AAe4WMJR2paKG6e3plGI2ZxP20-N6GanhamdRhpsaheSxdeXJsZyur2L6wmLplGS6D6ueeBhph22xjBopCuWODWYG4BeZV6N6zQHxKIeZeGVqo6Nm-uhJexUa0W3aDWvKgWeZJ6-RHq8-eZLR3K_GBaFZbJp6c5nA9UXQEcXw4SlK-S8Y-gZKIAQi6gISycTK8SiSecZ8uyCwASc82A-gpgcKjShciK-5Syd5g82coA-KsAhKj5aAxKj56AwAwywy4yeClyTKGIpSb88iiiSiaqDAx6DAI8DAMQrAei6KSy55j535Syv5_5gF1ABpn5LAYFGAEFyi0FsF8FHgyFIFZAmKSyy5n56A_AwF9FVATFP5kg1AHgZq5AFAUgXCXFYSega5GcpgQ8_FWAJciiJ8sAoyqc4yTKNF1FmyFAZKBCUlJg4KkKNKXw9iZKN5D5T8Jg95rSnA6CeaAAoihVil8HMoUrecsi0u_CZeZZZWhZAoJUYOuZcJuduaYLuW-RhRgAktStQCeRMmeZcCJVeXpYsgZYRQFU-dYC-SAG-R-Z-fFQcH-QBfoEBbAJxVRYCIRegMRUouKjBYagwEzghcIEhZZeFflTFfhRgJlThTIPxQVUZUVQosoqVQMJxZVRRbVb_FRXRWxRxWJSxblWJexaxZhTxbhWJauR5cJaJVReJcAJJSMmMmFU_ApWgK5YFcpapaChpVCtpRYLpbZfpaBR1WXB0qwBXH4C5dfBnNFQFYZSsm_LdZPPdY9Y3HsmgGHMgPIHQkAA)

look at the increasing values, it's looks very straight.

[image]

I want it to be a little more curvy, like below. Is there any option to do that?

[image]

the example taken from: https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/dai

Comment: Consider the Y-axis scale on your chart. If your values are, for example, between 0 and 1, it would look like a straight line if your Y-axis goes from 0-100. However, if you were to change the Y-axis scale from 0 to 1, you should get something like in the second image.

Comment: @Swiffy unfortunately this is not working as intended, you can check the link below.

tinyurl.com/2p9c7pkb

Comment: Your dataset is really wicked. I took a Math.min and Math.max of the data-array and got put these values in Y-axis: min:1.029869616162218, max:1.028328637473282 and this is the result: https://i.imgur.com/rPt4AVC.png

Comment: this is the same result that I got. you don't have to calculate min and max value, it's already been calculated by adding scale: true property.

Comment: Echarts can't do magic. It will display data from your series but it can not create points for you. If you give it a straight line to display, it will display a straight line. If you want a curve line, give it a curve line (and use `smooth: true` as said below to make it look more 'curvy'). So basically, the problem here comes from the data you put in the series.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-smooth) example

You need to set the smooth property to true as shown:

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
      type: 'line',
      smooth: true   //<- THIS property 
    }
  ]
};
```

To zoom in to your data and see the different heights,  you could try and implement [dragging](https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/how-to/interaction/drag). Results may depend on your dataset.

Comment: sorry, this only makes it line smooth, doesn't change the curve height. you can see my example on the question, you can play with it.

Comment: You will need to modify your scale for that or implement some interaction e.g dragging. I have added this to my answer. If your data points are very close, then you will not see large changes in height.